# How to detect if .Net 3.5 is present on the System?

Tags: .net, wpf, startup

I know this question has been answered in other post but it dosent solves my problem:

Senario:

i have developed an application .net framework 3.5 sp1 using WPF

When i run the application by clicking the executable i wish to check if the required .net Version is installed or else give a message to the user..... i tried all solution available on the net....

but if the Run the application on a machine which does not have .net framework or has a framework version lower that 3.5 .. its shows the crash screen 
[image: Crash screen]

My Code that i am currently using in App.Xaml.cs

```
//Check the registry entry for .NET Framework.
            RegistryKey frameworkRegistryKey =
                Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(DOT_NET_FRAMEWORK_KEY_PATH);
            if (frameworkRegistryKey != null)
            {
                //Check for the installed versions.
                string[] versionNames =
                    frameworkRegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames();
                double framework =
                    Convert.ToDouble(
                        versionNames[versionNames.Length - 1].Remove(0, 1));
                int servicePack = Convert.ToInt32(
                    frameworkRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(
                        versionNames[versionNames.Length - 1]).GetValue(
                            SERVICE_PACK, 0));
                //Check if the version is 3.5 Service Pack 1 or later.
                if ((framework < 3.5)
                    || ((framework == 3.5) && (servicePack < 1)))
                {
                    returnCode = ErrorCodesEnum.ERR_DOT_NET_FRAMEWORK;
                }
            }
```

I also doubt that if its possible as without the right libraries how will my application run

Any help or suggestions will be gr8

Comment: You wrote code that required .NET to be installed.  You escape that chicken-and-egg problem by adding a Setup and Deployment project to your solution.  Easy peasy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what you do, if minimum required .NET version is not installed on the system you can't detect it using a program targeting .NET since it won't run at all! You'll need to use a bootstrapper with your installer to detect the framework installation and install it as necessary.

Comment: Ok i got that thanks... could you elaborate on Bootstrapper and how to attach it with application...

Comment: It depends on the installer you're using but have a look at [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It sets up a bootstrapper for you for your installer.